# WebService JSON query exception

Tags: c#, json, web-services, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1

```
async private void webServiceGetPoints()
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var response = await client.GetAsync(new Uri("//private//"));
        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        JArray jsonVal = JArray.Parse(result) as JArray;
        dynamic taglist = jsonVal;

        foreach (dynamic tag in taglist)
        {
            Collection.Add(new Tag(tag.name, tag.description, tag.longitude, tag.latitude));
        }
    }
```

I've got a problem with that code. When I set this GET query to serwer it returns me a json. I tried to parse it to class using JSON.NET but when I do that it thorws me an exception. I don't know with one becouse it's open App.h.cs file an highlight the line: 
    if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();

Comment: If you don't know what exception...could post them all? Otherwise it is pretty difficult to know what is going on...

Comment: The problem is in:             foreach (dynamic tag in taglist)
            {
                Collection.Add(new Tag(tag.name, tag.description, tag.longitude, tag.latitude));
            }

Comment: It looks like is can't add Tag to collection with is ObservableCollection

Comment: @Criss If you could post the exact exception?

Comment: it's not a normal exception. Visual Studio open me a App.i.cs file and highlights the line: global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break(); thats it

Comment: A first chance exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in SYSTEM.CORE.NI.DLL

Comment: Probably your Json fails to convert correctly to the parameters required for your Tag class constructor... I recommend using a strongly typed converter like Json.net

Comment: For clarification: The auto generated App.i.cs holds the unhandled exception handler. That's where you end when an exception is not caught anywhere in your code and after that method is finished, your app will terminate (unless you handle it there). It is kind of a last chance to log your error.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing dynamic values into your Tag class constructor. Some values in there are probably not convertible into whatever your class expects (maybe they are null, or not even exist).

You can use a typed converter like Json.Net:

```
class TagData
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int longitude { get; set; }
    //...
}

var item JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TagData>>(result);
```

Especially with data from web services you should never rely on dynamic and always use something that checks correct conversion.